# Find the first occurrence of a value in a row and return cell next to it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find in a row the first occurrence of "Sick" and get the date on the right next to it. Any ideas?

We have tried this, but believe that there is an easier way:

```
=SI.ERROR(INDICE(D2,COINCIDIR("Sick",C2,0)),SI.ERROR(INDICE(F2,COINCIDIR("Sick",E2,0)),INDICE(H2,COINCIDIR("Sick",G2,0))))
```

In English:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D2,MATCH("Sick",C2,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(F2,MATCH("Sick",E2,0)),INDEX(H2,MATCH("Sick",G2,0))))
```

I want to find an easier method, because I have to do this for several tables with different dimensions

Comment: Will you only be searching 1 row at a time? If so, something like this could work for you: `=INDEX(D2:I2,MATCH("Sick",C2:H2,0))`

Comment: Oh, maybe I should have mentioned this, sick can be repeated:

Comment: A     B             C       D             E     F             G                               H        J
Row 2    ok    10/04/2019    sick    11/04/2019    ok    12/04/2019  sick     Date           so I need to find the first occurence of sick in a row and the date that is next to it. :)

Comment: Did you try the index/match formula?  It does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

When everything is in one row:

```
    A     B             C       D             E     F             G
Row 2    ok    10/04/2019    sick    11/04/2019    ok    12/04/2019
```

Then following formula solves your issue:

```
=INDEX(B2:G2;1;MATCH("sick";B2:G2)+1)
```

This means : in B2:G2, verify if "sick" can be found, and in case yes, take the column next to it (hence the `+1` as `MATCH()` returns the column number).

When everything is in one column:

This is exactly the point of the `VLookup()` function: look at following example:

```
1      A             B            C
2                title          Date
3                   ok    10/04/2019
4                 sick    11/04/2019
5                   ok    12/04/2019
```

Use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP("sick";B1:C4;2)
```

This yields the value `11/04/2019` (after the correct cell formatting, of course).

Meaning: look for the value "sick" in the table B1:C4, and use the corresponding value for the 2nd column (containing the requested date).

Comment: @tigeravatar: You're right, I've adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: ok, this would work brilliant, but sick may appear more than once per row. Row looks like this: healthy data; sick date; healthy date; sick date; mid healthy date.....45 columns like that with a health state and a date (90 total) and I want to find the first appearance of sick and the corrsponding date :)

Comment: @RebeccaPeelJoanne Did you try the index/match formula?  It does exactly what you're looking for.